# MVC View and AbstractView - why both?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm starting to learn about MVC-based applications being that I'm getting into some heavier JavaScript work and it's becoming unbearable to sift through spaghetti code to update things. I'm reading through [O'Reilly's Essential Actionscript 2.0](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596006525.do) chapter on the MVC pattern as I've heard that it's pretty informative. Here's a quick question that I had:

In the book they setup the views using a View interface and a concrete class called AbstractView. The AbstractView class actually implements the functions from the View interface plus a few helpers, but you'd still have to create your own custom view class(es) with additional logic to do anything useful.

So, what is the point of creating a View interface, whose only purpose is to be used when an AbstractView object is instantiated? They go on to say that to actually create a usable view for your application, you'd need to create your custom class that extends the AbstractView class. Doesn't this make the View/AbstractView inheritance unnecessary?

Shouldn't you just have one abstract class, View, that implements the basic functions (as AbstractView does), and then create your custom views that inherit from View? I don't see the reasoning behind having a View interface ***and*** an AbstractView class if you're never going to bypass the AbstractView class to only inherit from View.

What benefit(s) am I missing?

EDIT: Here's the (ActionScript) sample code that they use:

```
// -------------- View Class --------------
interface mvc.View {
  // Sets the model this view is observing.
  public function setModel (m:Observable):Void;

  // Returns the model this view is observing.
  public function getModel ( ):Observable;

  // Sets the controller for this view.
  public function setController (c:Controller):Void;

  // Returns this view's controller.
  public function getController ( ):Controller;

  // Returns the default controller for this view.
  public function defaultController (model:Observable):Controller;
}

// -------------- AbstractView Class --------------
class mvc.AbstractView implements Observer, View {
  private var model:Observable;       // A reference to the model.
  private var controller:Controller;  // A reference to the controller.

  public function AbstractView (m:Observable, c:Controller) {
    setModel(m);

    if (c !== undefined) {
      setController(c);
    }
  }

  // Returns the default controller for this view.
  public function defaultController (model:Observable):Controller {
    return null;
  }

   // Sets the model this view is observing.
  public function setModel (m:Observable):Void {
    model = m;
  }

   // Returns the model this view is observing.
  public function getModel ( ):Observable {
    return model;
  }

   // Sets the controller for this view.
  public function setController (c:Controller):Void {
    controller = c;

    // Tell the controller this object is its view.
    getController( ).setView(this);
  }

   // Returns this view's controller.
  public function getController ( ):Controller {
    if (controller === undefined) {
      setController(defaultController(getModel( )));
    }

    return controller;
  }

  public function update(o:Observable, infoObj:Object):Void {
  }
}
```

Comment: "an abstract View class and a concrete class called AbstractView" -- I think you meant the other way around! :)

Comment: That may be part of my confusion--in the book, the View class most definitely is abstract and the AbstractView class *implements* the function stubs from View.

Comment: After taking a look at their sample again, they are actually implementing View as an interface, not an abstract class. My apologies for the confusion there. I suppose this is more of a question about why you would want to setup the interface->concrete class->concrete class inheritance chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I might not agree with the naming convention, in practice it does make sense, in the first level you have the definition of the interface that needs to be implemented. In not giving it any functionality it can be implemented any way you want, there are no assumptions being made. In the derived class 'AbstractView' as O'Reilly calls it (per your description) probably implements the most common functions in a reasonable way, but leaves room for specialisation. Some toolkit usually go one step further and then give you a simple fully functional implementation of the class in question.

*Edit*

After looking at the example that Xenthyl, i saw another reason for this separation, the `AbstractView` is not *just* a view it is also an `Observer`. So another reason to separate the base implementation from the Interface is too keep another interfaces implementation out of it.

In general what they seem to be doing is defining abstract interfaces that can be composed to higher order classes. But the interface is not polluted with

- an implementation, and from that an assumption of functionality
- another interface

This way the `View` interface can be used without having to be an `Observer` and vice versa.

Also from the language point of view as the 'View' is declare an 'interface' in Actionscript it cannot implement any functions, it can only contain definitions, [see adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f41.html). Other languages like c++ don't have the `interface` keyword and therefore will trigger different approaches.

When developing, unless you apply a very strict approach you might not go that route, unless you are developing a library a lot of times there is only one class that will implement a certain interface, you might not even have the abstract interface as it is shown here but just the concrete class. Eventually when you need a second or third implementation of the same type of object you would extract an interface, you might mix some implementation in it, or not. But they are trying to show you good practices so they are possibly overengineering things for demonstration purposes.

Does this make a little bit more sense ?

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason why this approach used by O'Reilly is preferable to merging View and AbstractView into a single, abstract class that you inherit from with custom classes? This setup is really only useful if someone wanted to bypass the AbstractView class and reference the View interface for the bare minimum that is required, right? In that case, though, you still actually need to implement what's outlined in View using essentially what's in AbstractView. It just seems very redundant to me.

Comment: Having never worked with ActionScript before, I didn't realize that the language doesn't actually support abstract classes. So, your point about building up a higher order class from multiple interfaces makes perfect sense here. I think you are also spot on in saying that a different language (ie. one supporting abstract classes) would approach this differently. Ultimately I think their naming convention with AbstractView being used for something that is not quite abstract is what threw me off. Thanks so much for clearing things up, Harald!